# How do I dynamically create a _global variable? Like: _global.eval("var" + i)

Tags: arrays, variables, actionscript-2, eval, global

I'm pretty sure eval doesn't work this way, but it gets the idea across. I'm trying to dynamically create global variables; here's my code:

```
var ti_arr:Array = new Array;
_global.a = new Object;

for (var t=0; t<group_count-1; t++) {
    numOfItems = group_nodes[t].childNodes.length;
    ti_arr = "tab_info" add t;
    // <-- I want to define a global array with the name held in ti_arr here

    for (var i=0; i<numOfItems; i++) {   
        eval(ti_arr)[i].a.name = tempNode.attributes.name; //<-- or give the array global scope here
        eval(ti_arr)[i].a.value = tempNode.attributes.value;
    }
}
```

I need: tab_info1.a.name to have global scope.

Comment: Ultimately I just need to dynamically create a global array and assign values. Should I be going about it differently?

Answer (score 0):

I've been out of the actionscript loop for a while:
eval is bad.. brackets are good.

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=259717

It's explained simply here, not sure why so much searching on eval() didn't net me this sooner.

```
for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
    ti_arr = "new_array";

    _global[ti_arr] = new Array
    _global[ti_arr][i] = new Object

    _global[ti_arr][i].name = tempnode.name
}
```